# Inductor's self-resonant frequency: Do we want it to be high or low?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, resonance

Inductor selection always confuses me. There is a spec for inductors as self-resonant frequency. For example, on [digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/inductors-coils-chokes/fixed-inductors/196627?k=inductor), as SR frequency of inductors increase, the price may increase or decrease. But why? See this graph below, behavior of self resonant frequency response of the inductor:

[image: self resonant frequency response]

Assume we have a circuit board with SMPS has switching range in between 1-2 MHz and a few other analog blocks work in up to 4 MHz. In this case, is it smart to use an inductor with SR frequency below 1 MHz or over 4 MHz? And why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In this case, is it smart to use an inductor with SR frequency below 1
>   MHz or over 4 MHz?

Above the self resonant frequency the impedance of the "inductor" is capacitive i.e. it stops being like an inductor and exhibits the net impedance of a capacitor: -

[image]

A better picture would be the magnitude of the impedance: -

[image]

The inductor (and parasitic capacitance) form a parallel tuned circuit.

It's the same with capacitors - internal inductances will generally mean that at some arbitrary high frequency a capacitor will behave like a series resonant LC: -

[image]

Comment: Ok that solves my problem. Could you suggest me a solution? I need an inductor with current rating at least 12 A, value must be between 33 uH and 100 uH, and my SMPS/Led Driver switching frequency is 2MHz. I couldn't find an inductor covers my requirements(http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/inductors-coils-chokes/fixed-inductors/196627) I used two of them on the link but they were useless so like you say their self resonant must be low. If I use two of this(http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/wurth-electronics-inc/74435588200/732-4241-1-ND/3672751) parallel for 41 uH, is it okey?

Comment: SRF wants to be at least 4 times higher than max switching frequency in my opinion and sometimes I go as far as 10x. You might be OK with the wurth inductor but it is a little close to my self-imposed limit.